# How to change properties on all Buttons in a form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, button, properties

Is it possible to change the properties of all the buttons on a form/project? E.g. I want to change the backcolor of all the buttons to Blue. Bearing in mind that some of the buttons are inside of panels.
Any Help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this generic extension methods which searches controls recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControlsRecursive<T>(this Control root) where T : Control
{
    if (root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        Control parent = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T)
                yield return (T)child;
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Find all buttons and set the `BackColor`:

```
var allButtons = this.GetChildControlsRecursive<Button>();
foreach (Button btn in allButtons)
    btn.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

**Edit** i've only just seen the VB.NET tag. Maybe it's helpful anyway. VB.NET doesn't have `yield`, so you could put it in an extension library in C#.

Here's a VB.NET approach which does not use deferred execution but returns a list:

```
Module ControlExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function GetChildControlsRecursive(Of T As Control)(root As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        If root Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("root")
        End If
        Dim controls As New List(Of T)
        Dim stack = New Stack(Of Control)()
        stack.Push(root)
        While stack.Count > 0
            Dim parent As Control = stack.Pop()
            For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
                If TypeOf child Is T Then
                    controls.Add(DirectCast(child, T))
                End If
                stack.Push(child)
            Next
        End While
        Return controls
    End Function
End Module
```

Usage:

```
Dim allButtons = Me.GetChildControlsRecursive(Of Button)()
For Each btn As Button In allButtons
    btn.BackColor = Color.Blue
Next
```

Comment: Nice, elegant solution!

Comment: Great answer @Tim +1. I've not used VB.Net for a long time but it looks like the [Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156729.aspx) keyword was added (although I'm not sure when)

Comment: @petelids: good to know, but i'm stuck with VS 2010 and .NET 4. It was added in VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

The form is a container of controls; you have a property available to you called Controls off the Form object.

[Form.Controls property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

This property will have a listing of all the controls on your form. You can then simply check each control using a loop or LINQ to see if it is of type `Button` and if it is, change the background color to blue.

Here's a simple code example using LINQ that'll grab all controls up to one layer deep on a form:

```
Dim buttons = Me.Controls.SelectMany(Function(control) control.Controls).OfType(Of Button)().Union(Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)())
For Each button As Button In buttons
    button.BackColor = Color.Blue
Next
```

You can see the other answer provided by Tim, or some online examples, if you have a more complicated form that has nested controls inside of nested controls on it.

Comment: In general i would also prefer this solution instead of my recursive approach. I've never needed this extension in productuon code. But OP stated explicitly that he needs to find them also in child-panels: _"Bearing in mind that some of the buttons are inside of panels."_